# Kotlin variables not getting initialized, but does when useless side-effect is enforced. Is this defined behaviour?

Tags: kotlin

Here is the code in question:

```
class A {
    val p = load()

    var a = 0 //.also {}
    var b = 2

    fun load() {
        a = 1
        b = 3
        println("init: $a $b")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val a = A()
    println("main: ${a.a} ${a.b}")
}
```

**Output #1** as-is:

```
init: 1 3
main: 1 2
```

**Output #2** with the .also {} uncommented

```
init: 1 3
main: 0 2
```

If we look at the compiled constructor for **Output #2** we see

```
   L12
    PUTFIELD A.a : I
   L13
    LINENUMBER 5 L13
    ALOAD 0
    ICONST_2
    PUTFIELD A.b : I
    RETURN
```

but in **Output #1** PUTFIELD A.a is conspicuously missing and there is only this:

```
   L2
    LINENUMBER 5 L2
    ALOAD 0
    ICONST_2
    PUTFIELD A.b : I
    RETURN
```

Is this defined behaviour or is it a bug?

Comment: I don’t know if it’s an oversight but I can guess the reason. With a bare 0 there may be an optimization to not initialize the variable and just rely on its default value of zero. With the also call it changes compiler behavior so the optimization goes away.